# Imacros script stopped working all of a sudden

Tags: imacros

I have written this code earlier. Previously it was working fine. But suddenly one day iMacros stopped working without I changed anything....
it stops at `line 19`

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:http://api.deathbycaptcha.com/decaptcher ATTR=VALUE:Send
```

Even when I set the `IGNOREERROR YES` 
Please help

```
VERSION BUILD=8300326 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !LOOP 1
URL GOTO=http://bootleggers.us/jail.php
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=/Users/dymphi/Desktop/ FILE=image.jpg WAIT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=HREF:http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image* CONTENT=EVENT:SAVEITEM
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO=api.deathbycaptcha.com/decaptcher?function=picture2&print_format=html
FRAME F=0
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:http://api.deathbycaptcha.com/decaptcher ATTR=NAME:username CONTENT=dbcname
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:http://api.deathbycaptcha.com/decaptcher  ATTR=NAME:password CONTENT=dbcpassword
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ACTION:http://api.deathbycaptcha.com/decaptcher ATTR=NAME:pict CONTENT=/Users/dymphi/Desktop/image.jpg
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:http://api.deathbycaptcha.com/decaptcher ATTR=VALUE:Send
TAG POS=6 TYPE=TD ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
TAB CLOSE
TAB T=1
FRAME F=0
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:/jail.php ATTR=ID:recaptcha_response_field CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/jail.php ATTR=VALUE:Continueplaying!
URL GOTO=http://bootleggers.us/jail.php
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Bustout!
filedelete name=/Users/dymphi/Desktop/image.jpg
WAIT SECONDS=110
```

Comment: what version of imacros/firefox you are using? If you r imacros has been updated to version 8.5.1 - you need to install latest 8.5.3 beta driver from official website since there are several issues fixed there

Answer (score -1):

I'm also using deathbycaptcha for solving captcha and my code works fine, you should set a timeout before submitting:

```
URL GOTO=http://api.deathbycaptcha.com/decaptcher?function=picture2&print_format=html
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:username CONTENT=username
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:password CONTENT=pass
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=NAME:pict CONTENT=/Users/dymphi/Desktop/image.jpg
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 30
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=TYPE:submit
TAG POS=6 TYPE=TD ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
TAB CLOSE
TAB T=1
SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
```

I tested it even when the image doesn't exist, my version of iMacros is 8.3.0. Hope it will work.

Comment: if there wasnt a captcha on the page it shouldnt upload anything so when i press sent it shouldt select any text and go on. but if there is nothing to copie then the marco just stops without an error code